# What are steps in making an operating system in C ?

Tags: c++, c, operating-systems, assembly

I am trying to make an my own OS. This is for educational purpose only, so that I get to understand the internals as well as get a good idea of low level programming. I have some prior application development experience  in C#/python/C++/C. I am a noob in assembly language(very less experience and knowledge). I understand that in writing an operating system,we can't go without assembly language.

Currently, I have just printed a string in assembly language in the boot sector using qemu and BIOS interrupts.
What I want is that, can someone specifically point out the steps that I need to follow to make my operating systems run C programs. So that, I can start writing my OS in C.
Any other piece of advice to help a newbie, regarding the same is also welcome.

Although, I have looked into many os development related tutorials/websites, I can't seem to find this information anywhere.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where to start?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)**

Comment: see also: [Is it possible to write an operating system in C?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/209667/is-it-possible-to-write-an-operating-system-in-c), [Are there any OS which are simple enough for learning?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/117973/are-there-any-os-which-are-simple-enough-for-learning) and multiple questions linked to these ([lack of research](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important) in this question feels pretty appalling)

Comment: I recommend PintOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot write *entirely* an operating system kernel in C, because by definition an OS is managing physical hardware resources, and some of them (at least on common hardware like x86) are not accessible in C (e.g. MMU, I/O ports, ...). So you'll need a little assembly. (perhaps most of them can be `asm` instructions inside C functions).

Then, look at [OsDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page), it gives you a lot of information about how to start.

You'll also learn a lot by extending existing free software OS: in particular, understanding how to write your own Linux kernel modules and drivers will teach you a lot. See http://kernelnewbies.org/